# How can Tomcat Server cache a POST request?

Tags: http, tomcat, caching, post, server

I am trying to run a `Single Page App` without a "backend" (no DB, sessions etc.) except for a `Tomcat Server` that will serve static assets.

However, I wish to cache `POST` requests (ephemerally, if possible survive server restart) so that users of my application can share these links with others.

When they point browser (`GET`) to a "cached" `POST URL` from a previous "session", browser must be able to `GET` this cached URL (both POST and GET will have same URL)

`POST` body that gets cached will contain `Content-Type: application/json`

Thanks for your inputs!

P.S.

In the current environment, I cannot use anything other than Tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I have created a Github Project here: https://github.com/vikikamath/CachingServlet